# How do I send all window alerts to one text box

Tags: javascript, dom, textbox, alert

I had an assignment that used window alerts so the user knew what was happening in a game. I have now got to update that game for a different assignment but this time the window alerts have to go into a text box. The text box has "Click on your selection" as a base text. How do I make the window alerts overwrite this text?

The code below is what I have for the window alerts:

```
function check(guess) {
    if (diamond == guess) {
        window.alert("Congratulations! You have found the diamond.")
        again = window.prompt("Would you like to play another game? Enter Y or N.", "y");
        if (again == "N" || again == "n") {
            window.alert("Thanks for playing.Goodbye.");
            window.close();
        } else {
            window.alert("The diamond has been hidden. You can now try again.");
            window.location.reload();
        }
    } else {
        number_of_guesses = number_of_guesses + 1;
        if (diamond < guess) {
            result = "lower"
        } else {
            result = "higher"
        }
        window.alert("Guess number " + number_of_guesses + " is incorrect. Diamond is " + result + ".");
    }
    if (number_of_guesses >= 3) {
        window.alert("Sorry, you have run out of guesses! The diamond was in box " + diamond);
        again = window.prompt("Would you like to play again? Enter Y or N. ", "y");
        if (again == "N" || again == "n") {
            window.alert("Thanks for playing. Goodbye.");
            window.close();
        } else {
            window.alert("The diamond has been hidden. You can now try again.");
            window.location.reload();
        }
    }
}
```

I now what to put all the window alerts into the one text box:

```
<INPUT TYPE="text" id="windowalerts" NAME="windowalerts" VALUE= "Click on a Selection " SIZE=30>
```

Can someone please tell me how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one simple ways is you can directly overwrite window's alert function in your javascript, and inside that overwritten function get that textbox's id and add value of alert there... **e.g.**

```
<input type="text" id="mytextbox"/>
window.alert = function(message) {
    document.getElementById('mytextbox').value = message;
}
```

Here is also a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/243qwkvf/2/) for your try

Comment: To do that do I have to give each window alert an id or make them a function? For example  window.alert1 = "Click on a selection"

Comment: Nope, just add this code on top of your scripts, so it will overwrite the default alert function....

Comment: @Michael : Than alert won't be showing any prompt in the browser, it will be a normal function like your check function

Comment: Ive just tried that but it removes the text box completely.

Comment: That's the full code I have: http://pastebin.com/Cxex4Qxd If I leave the code you suggested where it is then the box is still visible

Comment: To help me out you can paste this code in jsfiddle, so I can directly debug there aswell

Comment: write the window.alert = function(message) {} above your check function

Comment: add textbox in you html code and just window.alert function in your javascript code

Comment: @Michael You accepted the answer so I guess you got it, also upvote the answer .. :)

Comment: @Michael : here is a fiddle so that you can get idea about how to create fiddle, look at working fiddle and it will provide you a  solution aswell   -> https://jsfiddle.net/243qwkvf/2/

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly. Will upvote the answer :)